# Aligning the table to te center of the page in Markdown

Tags: html, css, alignment, markdown, center

I want to align the table to the center of the page, how ever the `<div align="center" <table> </div>` function does not work.

How would I be able to achieve this in markdown?

Code:

```
# <center>Lesson 1 Calculus 310</center>

<div align="center">

| Name | General Formula |  Formula |
| --- | ----------- | ----------- |
| Derivative | $$\frac{d}{dx} (f(x)^n)$$| $$ nx^{(n-1)}$$|
| Anti-derivative | $$\int_a^b f(x)^n \,dx$$ | $$\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + c$$|

</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: align="center" to center the text align not the table, try to add <table style="margin:0 auto;">

Comment: Did you find any response on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto"
```

Give this one to your table and your table's position will be in the center.

Thanks

Comment: Hi I have applied that yet it still doesnt work